# COBOL File Formatting

Tags: cobol

We are attempting to load a .txt file into Trillium for analysis, and a .cbl file as the data schema.

The .txt file has data that looks like this:

```
    Record 1: 1234560001001
    Record 2: 12345670001001
```

COLUMN_1 has a maximum of 7 chars, COLUMN_2 must be 4 chars, COLUMN_3 must be 3 chars.

I created a COBOL file like so:

```
    02 COLUMN_1 PIC X(07).
    02 COLUMN_2 PIC X(04).
    02 COLUMN_3 PIC X(03).
```

But Trillium has parsed it out like so:

```
    1234560 0010 01
    1234567 0001 001
```

I am unsure how to rectify this issue. Any thoughts?

---

Comment: If "COLUMN_1 has a maximum of 7 chars", then it may have fewer than 7 under some condition. What is that condition? Because `PIC X(07)` defines a fixed width field, It may be necessary to "parse" the `.txt` file based on that condition.

Comment: How did you expect it to parsed. It look like the correct parsing for the copybook

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to right justify your input records. Numerous ways of shuffling the data around. Simplest is probably

```
01 justright PIC X(14) JUSTIFIED RIGHT.
```

GnuCOBOL (and others as far as I know) also include support for

```
CALL "C$JUSTIFY" USING source-field "R" END-CALL
```

Modified in place to size of field. 14 in this case.

But if all you have is a foreign parser of the record layout, then as Rick commented, you may need to write code based on the rules for length of the data destined for COLUMN_1.